# How to use WebRequest in c#

Tags: c#, .net, api, webrequest

I'am trying to use example api call in below link **please check link**

http://sendloop.com/help/article/api-001/getting-started

My account is "code5" so i tried 2 codes to get systemDate.

**1. Code**

```
        var request = WebRequest.Create("http://code5.sendloop.com/api/v3/System.SystemDate.Get/json");
        request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

        string text;
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            text = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

**2.Code**

```
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://code5.sendloop.com/api/v3/System.SystemDate.Get/json");
        httpWebRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
        httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/json";
```

But i don't know that i use correctly api by above codes ?

When i use above codes i don't see any data or anything.

How can i get and post api to Sendloop.And how can i use api by using WebRequest ?

I will use api first time in .net so

**any help will be appreciated.**

Thanks.

Comment: Does this endpoint accept GET or POST or both?

Comment: i think i need get for api example in that link.But i will also need post in the future.So if you help me , i will be very glad sir.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you need to post your API key to the endpoint when making requests. Otherwise, you will not be authenticated and it will return an empty response.

To send a POST request, you will need to do something like this:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://code5.sendloop.com/api/v3/System.SystemDate.Get/json");
request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";

string postData = "APIKey=xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx";

request.Method = "POST";
ASCIIEncoding encoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
byte[] data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);
request.ContentLength = data.Length;
Stream newStream = request.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
newStream.Write(data, 0, data.Length); // Send the data.
newStream.Close();

string text;
var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
{
    text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: text shows  "{\"Success\":false,\"ErrorCode\":104,\"ErrorMessage\":\"Invalid API key\",\"ErrorFields\":[]}" string

Comment: @user3179063 you are getting that error, because you have not added your API Key.  You need to replace all the "x" you see above with your actual API key.  Until then, the API will continue to reject your requests.

Comment: sir if you have skype , please add me "SonerSevinc92" i will send you api key because it still gives same exception :(

Comment: @user3179063 I'm sorry, but I'm not Skyping. You need to replace the 'x' with your actual API key. If you don't have an API key, you need to request one.

Comment: Example api call : 

curl -d APIKey=xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx \
http://youraccount.sendloop.com/api/v3/System.SystemDate.Get/json

So how can i use "curl - d" ?

Comment: `HttpWebRequest` takes the place of curl in this case. It's one of the .NET managed HTTP libraries. You just need to replace 'xxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx' with your own API key.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     string userAuthenticationURI = 
>     "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="+ originZip + 
>     "&destinations="+ DestinationZip + "&units=imperial&language=en- 
>      EN&sensor=false&key=Your API Key";
> ```

```
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userAuthenticationURI))
            {
                HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(userAuthenticationURI);
                request.Method = "GET";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                var responseString = new 
StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseString);

            }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.